# How to print file path that caused fswatch to do something

Tags: linux, macos, inotify, inotifywait, fswatch

I use [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) to take some actions when a file changes. I use the following command:

```
fswatch -o -r '.' | while read MODFILE
do
    echo 'Some file changed, so take some action'
done
```

this works fine, if I change a couple files I see the following in the terminal:

```
Some file changed, so take some action
Some file changed, so take some action
Some file changed, so take some action
etc.
```

But I also wonder which file actually caused the action. So I checked the fswatch man page, which shows the following:

```
fswatch writes a record for each event it receives containing:
     -       The timestamp when the event was received (optionally).
     -       The path affected by the current event.
     -       A space-separated list of event types (see EVENT TYPES ).
```

But as said I don't see anything listed in my terminal. Does anybody know how I can show "*The path affected by the current event.*"?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately still no result..

Comment: Works fine on El Capitan with `fswatch 1.8.0` - just run it without your `while read ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Ah, without the `while read..` it indeed works! But I do need the `while read` to actually take the actions right? Would you know how I can edit my command to take an action while still printing the file paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, use this:

```
fswatch --batch-marker=EOF -xn . | while read file event; do 
   echo $file $event
   if [ $file = "EOF" ]; then 
      echo TRIGGER
   fi
done
```

If you want to save the names of the affected files in a list, you can do that like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
fswatch --batch-marker=EOF -xn . | while read file event; do
    if [ $file = "EOF" ]; then
       echo TRIGGER
       echo Files: "${list[@]}"
       list=()
    else
       echo $file $event
       list+=($file)
    fi
done
```

Comment: But with this code it takes the action for all files that have changed if it are more than one (which is often the case for me). What I actually need is for the code to first list all the files that have changed, and then to take an action only once. Is that also possible?

Comment: You can add a batch marker with `fswatch --batch-marker=EOF` then you will get all the files and `EOF` at the end of the batch and you can use that to trigger your processing.