# Is there a way to programmatically change the Emoji Panel on key press in System Settings?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've been trying to change it trough accessing the plist file but I cant find documentation on how to access it. I'm not sure if it's even possible.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. It's also not clear why your code is the same thing 4 times and what it has to do with your question.

Comment: im trying to change the show emoji & symbols to "do nothing" trough my application using swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `fswatch` to [detect which files changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35396947/3141234) inside my `~/Library/Preferences` folder, while I changed the setting back and forth. Sure enough, `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` ("Human Interface toolbox") came up as the result.

Next, I looked at its structured and saw the `AppleFnUsageType` key, which seemed pretty promising. I changed the setting back and forth in System Preferences again, while monitoring for specific changes to that key with:

```bash
watch -n 1 -d defaults read com.apple.HIToolbox AppleFnUsageType
```

And I saw the following results:

- `0` maps to "Do Nothing"
- `1` maps to "Change Input Source"
- `2` maps to "Show Emoji & Symbols"
- `3` maps to "Start Dictation (Press ︎ Twice)"

So you can set this setting via the terminal with:

```bash
defaults write com.apple.HIToolbox AppleFnUsageType -int 0
```

You *can* spawn a process to run `defaults` from your Swift program, but that's clunky and requires turning the App sandbox off. Ideally we'd just call the `UserDefaults` APIs, but that won't let us change values in the `com.apple.HIToolbox` domain (it only lets you change values for your own app's domain, or the global domain).

We can drop to a lower level and use [`CFPreferencesSetValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1515525-cfpreferencessetvalue) from CoreFoundation, which has  lets you do that. It's still fairly straight forward:

```swift
import Foundation

enum FnKeyUsageType: Int {
    case doNothing = 0
    case changeInputSource = 1
    case showEmojiAndSymbols = 2
    case startDictation = 3
}

CFPreferencesSetValue(
    "AppleFnUsageType" as CFString,
    FnKeyUsageType.doNothing.rawValue as CFNumber,
    "com.apple.HIToolbox" as CFString,
    kCFPreferencesCurrentUser,
    kCFPreferencesAnyHost
)
```

Comment: great work on figuring this out, thx for the help

Comment: Happy to hear! If this answer solved your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the right.

Comment: the problem that i have is that even tho it changes it, it doesnt reflect in the system, by example if i have it on emoji, and i make it switch to do nothing it will say do nothing but it will still be on emoji when i press the emoji(globe) key

Comment: System Preferences doesn’t listen for changes to underlying UserDefaults, so its UI can go stale like that. I don’t think they expect other things to change them, or if they do, they probably figure it’s a niche enough use case that it’s not worth worrying about. If that really an issue for you, then you can change the setting by scripting the System Preferences UI, though that’s obviously much more clunky.

Comment: that makes sense, thx for that nswer

Comment: @bibbletriple If you really want a _top_-notch UX, you can do both. If sysprefs is closed, use the `CFPreferencesSetValue` approach to set it more simply/quickly, and without needing to open sysprefs. If sysprefs is already opened on the keyboard pane, then you can take the AppleScript approach to update it the UI in-place. I wouldn't bother with that personally, but it could be cool.